Error message CPF4203 appeared during OPEN for file PFFLEED (C S D F)
I'm getting an Error when ever i'm trying to debug the RPGLE program within turnover. But compilation, there is no error
Error message CPF4203 appeared during OPEN for file LFFLEED (C S D F).
LFFLEED is a logical file
can any one help me how to overcome this problem

The text for CPF4203 is "Member &4 cannot be opened while UPDPROD(*NO)"
This means that Debug was started with UPDPROD(*NO) which means do not allow files in a production library to be opened for update.  File LFFLEED must be a logical over a physical file in a production library and is being opened for Update, thus the error.
If you want to be able to debug you will need to use UPDPROD(*YES) or to use another version of the files in a *Test library if you don't want to update any production files.

Thank you, @Scott, for your valuable comments.

STRDBG YOURPGM UPDPROD(*YES)

I have one more doubt @victor,@scott, If I worked on the Test library, can I use UPDPROD(*YES)?

The question here is which library contains the files you are working with. UPDPROD(*YES) allows changes to files in PROD libraries (regardless of which library you are working in). If all your files are in TEST libraries, then you simply do not need this option.

And if all your users have *ALLOBJ, and *QSECOFR, you don't have to worry about people not having access to objects, but it is not always a good idea. The default when creating a new library is for it to be labeled as *PROD. This affords the protection that you will not be able to update files during testing unless you explicitly indicate that you intend to do so. But if that library is really a test library, it can be more of a pain than a benefit. So best to mark test libraries as test, and production libraries as prod.
